# Can't access Dockerized Vue's localhost:8080 on host machine (despite EXPOSE-ing port)

Tags: docker, vue.js

I can't access my Vue app on `localhost:8080` anymore after Dockerizing the app.

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following contents:

```
 # Base the image off of the NodeJS image
 FROM node

 # Set the working directory to be the HOME directory
 WORKDIR /root

 # Install NPM dependencies early in the build process
 COPY ./package.json /root
 COPY ./package-lock.json /root
 RUN npm install

 # Specify what port will be available - necessary for VPC network
 EXPOSE 8080

 # Copy our application files to the image
 COPY ./.browserslistrc /root
 COPY ./.eslintrc.js /root
 COPY ./.env /root
 COPY ./babel.config.js /root
 COPY ./README.md /root
 COPY ./vue.config.js /root
 COPY ./public /root/public
 COPY ./src /root/src

 # Start the container running our Node app
 CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

(Before Dockerizing, `npm run serve` allowed me to access the Vue app through my web browser.)

Then I run the PS command `docker build`:

```
PS C:\Users\User\mealSocial-dev> docker build -t finalvue app
Sending build context to Docker daemon  126.8MB
Step 1/15 : FROM node
 ---> 448d0873ea84

[...]

Step 15/15 : CMD ["npm", "run", "serve", "--port", "\"8080\""]
 ---> Running in c4840f98e5dc
Removing intermediate container c4840f98e5dc
 ---> 904928fa859c
Successfully built 904928fa859c
Successfully tagged finalvue:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

...Then `docker run -p 8080:8080`:

```
PS C:\Users\User\mealSocial-dev> docker run -p 8080:8080 finalvue

> meal-app@0.1.0 serve /root
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
<s> [webpack.Progress] 0% compiling

[...]

DONE Compiled successfully in 8147ms11:39:59 AM
<s> [webpack.Progress] 100%    
App running at:    
- Local: http://localhost:8080/    
It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.    
Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/    
Note that the development build is not optimized.   
To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

Despite it saying `It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container. Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/`, I get `This page isn’t working. localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`:
[image]

I'm `EXPOSE`-ing the port in the `Dockerfile` and adding the `-p 8080:8080` tag when I run `docker run`. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you paste the content of the `hosts` file. Looks like you are using a windows machine. In that, it is generally located here - `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Also make sure you are hitting `http://localhost:8080` and **not** `https://localhost:8080` (**http** & **https** is the difference) on the browser.

Comment: can you add `--host 0.0.0.0` to `npm run serve` or `HOST = '0.0.0.0'` to your config and try again ?

Comment: @invad0r - That was it! Thank you so much! In `./vue.config.js`, I changed `host: localhost` to `host: 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from the comment section:

add `--host 0.0.0.0` to `npm run serve`

or

add `host: 0.0.0.0` to a config (`./vue.config.js`)

Comment: I had the same error today. In my case the host config was saved in `config/index.js` file. Add --host 0.0.0.0 didn't work in my case, but change host from `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` worked. Because when the host is localhost, only inside the Docker can access, but when the host is 0.0.0.0, it means outside of the Docker can access the app.